# Selenium: How to assert that image is displayed under a certain section of a webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, build-automation

I am attempting to write a test that is able to do the following:
1. Navigate to a website.
2. Navigate to a page under the menu.
3. Once in that page, assert that the image I want is displayed under a section labeled "SECTION".

Here is my code (approach 1):

```
public void test1() throws Exception {
   WebElement compare_image = driver.findElement(By.linkText("URL link where the image is located"));

   driver.get("website URL");

   WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("cssSelector for image from FireFox -> inspect element -> copy CSS selector"));

   assertEquals(image, compare_image); }
```

I am very new to Selenium and QA automation, so any detailed help would be appreciated as my google searches so far are coming up short. It is giving me an element not present exception for the findElement call, but I don't know why as I tried all the Bys I could get from inspect element.

Am I approaching this correctly? If not, what can I do differently?

Comment: So you want to verify that an element points to the image or you want to verify the image itself? e.g. IMG src is correct vs bit by bit comparison of two images?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check image is present or not under a section then you have to create a webelement for that section.

```
WebElement section= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img(@class=‘Section')"));
```

Now create an image element under section element.

```
WebElement image= section.findElement(By.xpath("//img(@class=‘Test Image')"));
```

Now check image is exist or not.

```
boolean imagePresent = image.isDisplayed();
```

Now assert on boolean result.

```
assertTrue(imagePresent, “No image is exist”);
```

**Note**: Please take care of locators for section and Image  as you didn’t provide Html for it. Code will work perfectly.